# External URL Images to show in Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox2, bootstrap-lightbox

I am designing a gallery that can link to dropbox URL's.

http://gregorydanelian.comule.com/ken/

When I click an image I want it to go to the lightbox gallery and then within the lightbox gallery there will be a link to the external image.

At the moment the first 6 image thumbnails skip the lightbox gallery and go straight to the link. E.g:

```
<a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]"         href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38631221/Masterplan/Slimming_Book_JPEG/small/001.jpg"><img class="group1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38631221/Masterplan/Slimming_Book_JPEG/small/001.jpg" title="Image Title" /></a>
```

The remaining images show the lightbox gallery...

Is it possible for the lightbox gallery to be linked up to URL images and preview in the slider?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to Add `data-lightbox` attribute to your `anchor` tag

```
<a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]" data-lightbox="thumbnail-x1" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38631221/Masterplan/Slimming_Book_JPEG/small/001.jpg">
<img class="group1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38631221/Masterplan/Slimming_Book_JPEG/small/001.jpg" title="Image Title" />
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm...I didn't change anything and went back onto the page and it worked! Seems refreshing the page whilst in lightbox stops the js from working again when you click another thumbnail.